# How to execute adb shell command right after boot

Tags: android, adb, arduino-c++

I am trying to create a simple Hello world module in C++ that will just do the printout of "Hello world". For now I can execute the binary hello manually on my adb shell connected to my android emulator but I would like to see it executed automatically right after or during boot process of the emulator. Now I am not sure if this possible since I guess it should start the adb shell also automatically!?

How can I achieve this.

For now I have:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world - our team try" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

hello.rc

```
service hello /vendor/bin/hello
    class main
    user oem_2990
    group oem_2990
    oneshot
```

Android.bp

```
cc_binary {
    name: "hello",
    init_rc: ["hello.rc"],
    vendor: true,
    
    local_include_dirs: ["src"],

    srcs: ["src/**/*.cpp"]
}
```

hello.mk

```
BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += vendor/blabla/hardware/hello/sepolicy
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += hello
```

hello.te

```
# hello service
type hello, domain;
type hello_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(hello)

# set_prop(hello, vendor_blabla_unconfig_prop)
```

file_contexts

```
/vendor/bin/hello      u:object_r:hello_exec:s0
```

Even after reading up some other pages and adapting my module it is still complaining with:

```
10-26 23:25:35.873     0     0 I init    : Parsing file /vendor/etc/init/hello.rc...
10-26 23:25:41.020     0     0 E init    : Could not start service 'hello' as part of class 'main': File /vendor/bin/hello(labeled "u:object_r:vendor_file:s0") has incorrect label or no domain transition from u:r:init:s0 to another SELinux domain defined. Have you configured your service correctly? https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials. Note: this error shows up even in permissive mode in order to make auditing denials possible.
```

Latest update and changes:

hello.rc

```
service hello /vendor/bin/hello
    class main
    user root
    group root
    oneshot
    seclabel u:r:hello:s0
```

hello.te

```
# hello service
type hello, domain;
type hello_exec, exec_type, file_type;

#init_daemon_domain(hello)

# set_prop(hello, vendor_blabla_unconfig_prop)
```

file_contexts

```
/vendor/bin/hello     seclabel u:r:hello_exec:s0
```

It seems that overcome the first issue but now the error msg changed to:

```
10-30 21:26:11.993     0     0 I init    : Parsing file /vendor/etc/init/hello.rc...
10-30 21:26:17.887     0     0 I init    : starting service 'hello'...
10-30 21:26:17.900     0     0 F init    : cannot setexeccon('u:r:hello:s0') for hello: Invalid argument
10-30 21:26:17.935     0     0 I init    : Service 'hello' (pid 597) exited with status 6 oneshot service took 0.047000 seconds in background
10-30 21:26:17.936     0     0 I init    : Sending signal 9 to service 'hello' (pid 597) process group...
```

Comment: You can use `adb wait-for-device`

Comment: The Android device is rooted?

Comment: @Robert, yes the device is rooted with adb root.